# Where (which log file) to look when one of the JMeters test do not run in Jenkins?

Tags: performance, plugins, jenkins, jmeter

I have 17 tests in a .jmx that I call from Jenkins. Out of this, 15 runs correctly and return meaningful results. However, the 2 last resturns with a run time of 0ms. I looked at the logs at there is no exception. My question is where (which log file) can I look in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options to detect that your test is doing what it should do.

- Assertions
- Result File
- Log file

The easiest one is using [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to check sampler response data. The most commonly used is [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

Next one is configuring JMeter to save request and response fields you're interested in. See  properties, starting from **jmeter.save.saveservice** in `jmeter.properties` file. Uncomment and set to true those, you feel may help you to get to the bottom of the issue

The next one is the most flexible and informative. I would suggest to use some logging to get things sorted out.  JMeter writes a file called `jmeter.log`. You can add Beanshell Pre Processor and Beanshell Post Processor to the sampler which run time is 0ms with something like:

In Post Processor:

```
log.info("Starting test " + sampler.getName() + " at " + new Date());
```

In Post Processor:

```
log.info("Response code " + prev.getResponseCode());
log.info("Response message " + prev.getResponseMessage());
log.info("Execution time " + prev.getTime());
```

etc. You can even see full response data in the log as

```
log.info(new String(data));
```

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on advanced Beanshell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

All stdout and stderr output from the Jenkins build will go to the console output at [Jenkins URL]/job/[job name]/[build number]/console

If you don't see anything useful there, the best approach is to run the JMeter tests outside Jenkins, but on the same machine and under the same user environment that Jenkins would use. You may need to enable some extra debugging info; see [this link](http://www.sourcepole.ch/debugging-jmeter-tests) for some tips.